# How to determine equivalent circuit of inductor

Tags: inductor, spice

I'm wondering what is the best model for a real inductor.
I used RLC parallel circuit to explain inductor, however the simulation result  is not well fitting to experiment data.
I'm wondering how to plot the best equivalent circuit of an real inductor 
For example, Coilcaraft's SPICE model [image: Coilcaraft's SPICE model]looks better than RLC parallel circuit, however I can't find any paper which introduce this kind of model. Does the scheme has a reasonable physical meaning?

Comment: Check this: http://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/inductance.htm. (I personally recommend you to search "real inductor equivalent" on Google Images)

Comment: *...the best model for a real inductor* A **Model** is just what it says it is, a model. So it is **always** a limited representation of reality. The best is reality,  a model is always worse and will **never** fully represent reality. So the question you need to answer is "what model is good enough for my purposes ?".

Comment: Hi Rhat, I have check many times on Google Images, and these models are too simple, it can't fit experiment data well. However I didn't find another different model except Coilcraft's.

Comment: Hi FakeMoustache, you're right. I think best is not a good word what I want. As what you said I want a more detailed model than RLC parallel circuit.

Comment: A 3D finite element model is possibly as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering what is the best model for a real inductor

Simple answer is "it depends".

It depends on how you are using the inductor. For instance if you are using the inductor in a buck converter then you will be interested in its inductance for sure (because this stores the energy transferred) but you will also be interested in the series DC resistance because this limits the energy you can transport from input to output. You will likely be also interested in parallel capacitance in that you want the self resonant frequency (formed by L and C) to be significantly higher than the buck converter's switching frequency.

Would you be interested in the series DC resistance increasing with frequency (aka skin effect)? Possibly not so, the model you develop will probably not contain this feature. However, the Coilcraft model does not factor in core saturation and hysteresis and these are of significant interest to the designer in switch mode power supplies.

Would you be interested in transmission line or distributed capacitance effects for this type of application (buck converter)? Almost certainly not but, if you were designing a coil to base load a monopole antenna then you almost certainly would be.

So it depends.

Answer (score 0):

> "simulation result is not well fitting to experiment data"

I would say that manufacturer's model is as best as you can get. It is likely based on years of engineering and experiments with material properties of their product. They might have white papers on this subject, but I could be a bit optimistic here.

The likely cause of mismatch between your simulations and data is in other components of your circuit, parasitics/limitations of your driver, parasitics of capacitors involved, diodes, PCB trace imperfections/cross talks, ground bouncing, etc. You need to look into your prototype and insert into simulation all potential parasitics.

Comment: Thank you for your explaination. However it's difficult to find a paper about Coilcraft's model.

Comment: I am not sure what your concern is. The manufacturer knows better how their coil is designed, which part is non-linear, and how parasitics is distributed. They give you an answer - the SPICE model. Every product has design specifics, and the model reflects this. Are you saying that their model is brutally incorrect, and you have accounted for all imperfections in your experimental setup, but still the waveforms are too far from the simulation output?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm just wondering how to find the unknown parameters in this model by some physical equations.